# Unable to get any input from a JButton, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I've searched for a stupid amount of time trying to work it out, but for some reason It won't work. I'm pretty new to java, so my jframe is a bit of a mess but that doesn't seem to be the problem, whatever I do I can't get a response from button 1, what am I doing wrong?
Also there are a few unimplemented things in the class, just ignore them as I haven't had a chance to add them yet, as I can't seem to get past this.

```
public class First{
        private static JButton b1;
        private static JButton b2;
        private static JButton b3;
        private static int GetColor;
        private static Container content;

        public static void main(String[] args){
                JFrame f = new JFrame("test");
                f.setSize(300,100);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                Container content = f.getContentPane();
                content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                int GetColor = 1;
                if(GetColor==1){
                content.setBackground(Color.blue);
                }else{
                GetColor = 1;
                content.setBackground(Color.blue);
                }
                JButton b1 = new JButton("Blue");
                content.add(b1);
                JButton b2 = new JButton("Red");
                content.add(b2);
                JButton b3 = new JButton("Green");
                content.add(b3);                
                f.setVisible(true);

                Handler h = new Handler();
                b1.addActionListener(h);
                b2.addActionListener(h);
                b3.addActionListener(h);
        }                       
        private static class Handler implements ActionListener{
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                        Object src = a.getSource();
                        ProcessSrc(src);
                        }
                }
                private static void ProcessSrc(Object src){

                        if(src.equals(b1)){
                                System.out.println("f");

                        }


        }
}
```

Everything that is needed should be there.

Comment: @Cyrille Ka, you beat me to the edit by mere seconds :D Niall: Prepend code lines by four spaces to have them formatted as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the variable `b1`. Replace

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Blue");
```

with

```
b1 = new JButton("Blue");
```

Comment: Thanks, all sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem, you are redeclaring b1,b2, and b2 in method main, leaving static variables b1,b2,b3 as null. To fix remove the word "JButton" when initializing your buttons.